# Extend Wordpress Latest Dockerfile

Tags: wordpress, docker, dockerfile

I need to modify the wp-config.php file for the Wordpress:latest Dockerfile but I notice it's generated as part of the image's init process. Is there a way to add an additional line to the config without forking the whole image? I need to add 1 line of additional config. Not sure what the best practice is on this these days. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are different ways. the easiest way would be to go inside of the builded and running image and change the line of you config file.

if the container runs you can access it with

```
docker exec -it <imageid> sh (or bash, whatever OS you use)
```

then search your file and change it with a local editor. then you could save or commit your image to save the changes permanently.

```
docker save / docker commit
```

second way is to overwrite your file with a `COPY` command.

```
docker cp foo.txt mycontainer:/foo.txt
```

i am not sure if its usefull to volume mount the folder and change it directly on your host.

Comment: Ideally I'd like to hook into the startup process so I can extend the Dockerfile instead of creating a copy of the base of the image. That leaves a smoother upgrade path in the future.

Comment: @motleydev as you can see here https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6982 there is a discussion about pre-start and stop hooks but as you can read its not implemented yet. (as far as i know)